# Can RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) or Postfix Notation be derived by Regular Expression

Tags: regex, rpn

I was wondering if I can define a Regular Expression to check whether a given input matches the RPN expression , i.e. whether the given input is valuid or not?

I am not very familiar with Regex unfortunately, so I was wondering if it is possible to define a regular expression to validate the input for postfix.

Many thanks
Taz

Answer (score 11):

Formally, no; RPN would require a context-free grammar, which regular expressions cannot express.  However, it might be possible to do so with a "regular expression" package or library, since they can contain features that are outside of the formal definition of regular expressions.

Comment: +1 for mention of CFG and limitations of the standard definition of a regular expression.